# MomentJS: Use the default strings instead of custom

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

Using moment.js 2.7, I want to use custom strings for timestamps. I looked at the docs and found that I simply do something like so:

```
moment.lang('en', {
    relativeTime: {
        future: "the future",
        past: "the past",
        s: "soon",
        m: "%d minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h: "%d hour",
        hh: "%d hours",
        d: "%d day",
        dd: "%d days",
        M: 'never',
        MM: 'never',
        y: 'a long time',
        yy: 'a long time'
    }
});
```

However, I'd like to go back to using the default strings in another part of my code and was wondering if there is a quick way to set it back to the default, as opposed to setting it back manually like so:

```
moment.lang('en', {
    relativeTime: {
        future: 'in %s',
        past: '%s ago',
        s: 'a few seconds',
        m: 'a minute',
        mm: '%d minutes',
        h: 'an hour',
        hh: '%d hours',
        d: 'a day',
        dd: '%d days',
        M: 'a month',
        MM: '%d months',
        y: 'a year',
        yy: '%d years'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can define the custom case like this:

```
moment.lang('en-custom', {
    relativeTime: {
        future: "the future",
        past: "the past",
        s: "soon",
        m: "%d minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h: "%d hour",
        hh: "%d hours",
        d: "%d day",
        dd: "%d days",
        M: 'never',
        MM: 'never',
        y: 'a long time',
        yy: 'a long time'
    }
});
```

then load it where you need it:

```
moment.lang("en-custom");
```

This way you don't mess with defaults.